# How to display selected taxonomy of an article in Rest view in drupal 8

Tags: rest, view, drupal-8

How to display selected taxonomy of an article in Rest view in drupal 8

I have created a view with rest export as follows

Format = Serializer

Settings = Fields , Settings

Fields :

Content: Title
Content: Category

Under category i have choosed the below settings:

[image]

Filter criteria

Content: Published (= Yes)
Content: Content type (= News)

But when i view the json, the category field, selected  taxonomy term is not displaying.
[image]

Comment: I fixed this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have created the rest view in Drupal 8 with Article content type for following fields

1. Title
2. Tag

Below the export views code change the your project UUID and import it.

```
uuid: 435345-345ty-4354-35345f-534534fdf
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - field.storage.node.field_tags
    - node.type.article
  module:
    - node
    - rest
    - serialization
    - user
id: test_rest_view
label: 'test rest view'
module: views
description: ''
tag: ''
base_table: node_field_data
base_field: nid
core: 8.x
display:
  default:
    display_plugin: default
    id: default
    display_title: Master
    position: 0
    display_options:
      access:
        type: perm
        options:
          perm: 'access content'
      cache:
        type: tag
        options: {  }
      query:
        type: views_query
        options:
          disable_sql_rewrite: false
          distinct: false
          replica: false
          query_comment: ''
          query_tags: {  }
      exposed_form:
        type: basic
        options:
          submit_button: Apply
          reset_button: false
          reset_button_label: Reset
          exposed_sorts_label: 'Sort by'
          expose_sort_order: true
          sort_asc_label: Asc
          sort_desc_label: Desc
      pager:
        type: mini
        options:
          items_per_page: 10
          offset: 0
          id: 0
          total_pages: null
          expose:
            items_per_page: false
            items_per_page_label: 'Items per page'
            items_per_page_options: '5, 10, 25, 50'
            items_per_page_options_all: false
            items_per_page_options_all_label: '- All -'
            offset: false
            offset_label: Offset
          tags:
            previous: ‹‹
            next: ››
      style:
        type: serializer
      row:
        type: fields
        options:
          inline: {  }
          separator: ''
          hide_empty: false
          default_field_elements: true
      fields:
        title:
          id: title
          table: node_field_data
          field: title
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: false
            ellipsis: false
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: string
          settings:
            link_to_entity: false
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: title
          plugin_id: field
        field_tags:
          id: field_tags
          table: node__field_tags
          field: field_tags
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: target_id
          type: entity_reference_label
          settings:
            link: false
          group_column: target_id
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          plugin_id: field
      filters:
        status:
          value: '1'
          table: node_field_data
          field: status
          plugin_id: boolean
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: status
          id: status
          expose:
            operator: ''
          group: 1
        type:
          id: type
          table: node_field_data
          field: type
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          operator: in
          value:
            article: article
          group: 1
          exposed: false
          expose:
            operator_id: ''
            label: ''
            description: ''
            use_operator: false
            operator: ''
            identifier: ''
            required: false
            remember: false
            multiple: false
            remember_roles:
              authenticated: authenticated
            reduce: false
          is_grouped: false
          group_info:
            label: ''
            description: ''
            identifier: ''
            optional: true
            widget: select
            multiple: false
            remember: false
            default_group: All
            default_group_multiple: {  }
            group_items: {  }
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: type
          plugin_id: bundle
      sorts:
        created:
          id: created
          table: node_field_data
          field: created
          order: DESC
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: created
          plugin_id: date
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          exposed: false
          expose:
            label: ''
          granularity: second
      header: {  }
      footer: {  }
      empty: {  }
      relationships: {  }
      arguments: {  }
      display_extenders: {  }
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - request_format
        - url.query_args
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      tags:
        - 'config:field.storage.node.field_tags'
  rest_export_1:
    display_plugin: rest_export
    id: rest_export_1
    display_title: 'REST export'
    position: 1
    display_options:
      display_extenders: {  }
      path: testreset
      pager:
        type: some
        options:
          items_per_page: 10
          offset: 0
      style:
        type: serializer
        options:
          formats:
            json: json
      row:
        type: data_field
        options:
          field_options:
            title:
              alias: ''
              raw_output: false
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - request_format
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      tags:
        - 'config:field.storage.node.field_tags'
```

See rest output
[image]